# how can user_DEPENDENCIES read from the procedure

Tags: oracle

If I run this query :

> SELECT DISTINCT U.REFERENCED_NAME,  U.REFERENCED_TYPE 
>   FROM  USER_DEPENDENCIES U 
>   where U.name IN('P_CREATE_T')

It will give me :

```
  U.REFERENCED_NAME |  U.REFERENCED_TYPE
  random_name_table | table
```

If I drop this table random_name_table :

> drop table random_name_table

and I run the dependecie query It will give me this:

```
        U.REFERENCED_NAME        |  U.REFERENCED_TYPE
  BIN$6WfJh8MWWGngQ3ATqMDOpQ==$0 | table
```

I know the result is related to recycle bin,  But what I am asking is there a way that shows the table even if its droped ? I mean shouldnt the depency query read from the procedure and not from the database ? If not is there a query that reads from the procedure and not from database ?

---

Edit

ok I will make it clear :

my question USER_DEPENDENCIES read from the procedure or the database ?
My second question does the recycle bin always shows ? I mean is there times where the result of the recylebin disapear ?

Comment: What does `read from the procedure` mean to you? Data are kept in the recycle bin(if it's `ON`) until you issue `purge recyclebin` statement or drop an object(table or index) with `purge` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle automatically logs dependency changes every time you create, drop or modify an object. This information is stored in the Data Dictionary views. You can find more info here: [Schema Object Dependencies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/dependencies.htm)

That said to answer your question, `USER_DEPENDENCIES` doesn't read, but it's updated every time you change your procedure. When you drop the table, sending it to the bin, the dependency is missing (and you can't compile it if you don't recreate the table).

So `USER_DEPENDENCIES` is a view, it read from the database not from your procedure. The recycle bin result will stay there until your procedure stays invalid (you can re-compile, with the table, or delete it to fix that).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand the question.

If you want to find the original name of an object in the recyclebin, you can

```
SELECT original_name
  FROM user_recyclebin
 WHERE object_name = 'BIN$6WfJh8MWWGngQ3ATqMDOpQ==$0'
```

That should give you the `RANDOM_TABLE_NAME` that you dropped.

I'm not sure, though, that this is your question.  I have no idea what it means to "read from the procedure and not from the database".

Answer (score 1):

Just another try to make clear meaning of the question: "procedure" is a code. Code is a way to describe execution algorithm and didn't store anything at all, but code and some constants which initialized when execution starts.
So anything your procedure code "read" (if any) comes from "database" (disk storage and cache) and nowhere else.

If you question is about what `user_dependencies` is, then answer "is a view" :

```
create or replace view sys.user_dependencies
(name, type, referenced_owner, referenced_name, referenced_type, referenced_link_name, schemaid, dependency_type)
as
select o.name,

-- ... skipped code ...

from 
  sys."_CURRENT_EDITION_OBJ"   o, 
  sys.disk_and_fixed_objects   po,
  sys.dependency$ d, sys.user$ pu

where 
-- ... another skipped code ...
```

`sys._current_edition_obj` is another view:

```
create or replace view sys._current_edition_obj as
select 
  -- ... skipped ...
from obj$ o, user$ u
where 
  -- .. skipped ...
```

sys.obj$ and sys.user$ are internal Oracle tables.